# Forge Viewer Events documentation

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I have found a few Autodesk.Viewing.SOME_EVENT events floating around in samples, currently using these:

```
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, selectionChanged);
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT, geomLoaded);
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT, treeCreated);
```

but cannot find any documentation enumerating all the possible events (there are scripts ive seen to subscribe to all event listeners: [event monitor](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/event-monitor-viewer)

but that information should be in the documentation somewhere right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [here](https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/docs/Autodesk.Viewing.html#event:SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT):
[image]

All frequently used events are listed and briefly documented there.

Comment: thank you! it would be nice if this: https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/developers_guide/overview/ pointed to the existence of this: https://autodeskviewer.com/viewers/latest/docs/